# How do I transfer Sqlite data to Mysql using Pentaho Data Integration(PDI)?

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

Hi so I have a webApp on local server that writes in a sqlite database. I want to transfer this data from Sqlite server to Mysql server.

How do I do that using Spoon, pentaho.

Answer (score 1):

it's a simple task
create two database connection first one is sqlite and second one is mysql.
after that add table input step for sqlite connection. add table output for mysql connection in transformation.